# Configure java AWS sdk client to write to local S3 bucket (localstack)

Tags: java, amazon-s3, localstack

So i am able to configure a local s3 bucket using localstack with the following command

```
aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4572 s3 mb s3://mytestbucket
```

How am I able to change the configuration for the java AWS SDK in order to write/read from/to this bucket instead of remote aws s3?

I have looked at the configuration but not able to find any tangible

Answer (score 13):

This is done via the endpoint configuration within the AWS S3 SDK when creating the client. For example:

```
final AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration endpoint = new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration(s3Endpoint, REGION);
        final AmazonS3 client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withEndpointConfiguration(endpoint)
            .build();
```

The endpoint can be a string like `http://localhost:4572` (where the port number needs to be whatever port s3 in localstack is listening on - by default 4572)

Answer (score 5):

Now the s3 endpoint is updated in localstack .

Please use the below url :
http://s3.localhost.localstack.cloud:4566

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the above url is working actually and i can't find this mentioned anywhere in documentation. can you please update the answer with the documentation reference. so that will refer all the services not only s3.